# Python dataclass default factory with data from another field

Tags: python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I have a dataclass with a field of metadata,
I want to extract info from it to put in other field in the dataclass, but I'm not sure if it's possible/advisable.

I tried something like that:

```
def get_platform_from_metadata(metadata: pd.DataFrame) -> str | None:
    platform = metadata['platform'].iloc[0]
    if platform:
        return platform_mapper.get(platform[:-1])
    return None


@dataclass(frozen=True, slots=True)
class Data:
    metadata: field(default_factory=pd.DataFrame)
    features_details: field(default_factory=pd.DataFrame)
    platform: field(default_factory=lambda: get_platform_from_metadata(metadata=metadata))
```

But the IDE is angry at me because he does not recognize the metadata when it's in the lambda.

I'm using python 3.10.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no possibility using the default_factory. In the docs from dataclasses it's states, that:

> `default_factory`: If provided, it must be a zero-argument callable that will be called >when a default value is needed for this field. Among other purposes, this can be used >to specify fields with mutable default values, as discussed below. It is an error to >specify both default and default_factory.
> [source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.field)

But a possibility would be to use `__post_init__` this method will be called right after `__init__` as of the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#post-init-processing). You could use this to solve your problem as followed:

```py
def get_platform_from_metadata(metadata: pd.DataFrame, dflt="") -> str:
    platform = metadata['platform'].iloc[0]
    if platform:
        return platform_mapper.get(platform[:-1], dflt)
    return dflt

@dataclass(frozen=True, slots=True)
class Data:
    metadata: pd.DataFrame = field(default_factory=pd.DataFrame)
    features_details: pd.DataFrame = field(default_factory=pd.DataFrame)
    platform: str = field(init=False)

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.platform = get_platform_from_metadata(self.metadata, "")
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Is there a way to convince mypy that `platform` has type `str` rather than `str | None`?

Comment: @sid-kap You should be able to provide a default Str, like the empty string and the still change it in `__post_init__`

Comment: `get_platform_from_metadata` should always return a `str`, either one extracted from the `metadata` argument or a default `str` instead of `None`.